# Problem with underscore (_) in lua loop

Tags: luatex, lua, luacode

The next code gives the error: `Missing $ inserted.` This is because one of the keys is `c_a`. How to modify the loop to use `c_a`?

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
\parindent = 0pt
\begin{luacode}
tp=tex.print
z = {}

ap = "a'"
bp = "b'"

z.a = {5,2}
z.b = {3,-2}
z.c_a = {3,2}
z[ap] = {99,0}
z.bp = {66,55}

tex.print("The stored coordinates are : "..'\\\\')
-- z.c_a = nil
for k,v in pairs(z) do
   tp(k) tp(tostring(" represents :")) tp(tostring("(" .. v[1]..","..v[2]..")"))
   tex.print('\\\\')
end     
\end{luacode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I left them here but as commented in your last question it's confusing to use variable names matching your keys. Here you define `bp` but do not use it,whereas the similar `ap`  variable is used to access the key `a'`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I agree it's confusing but this defines the points given to start my geometrical figures. For the user `z["a'"],z["b'"] =  o:set_rotation (math.pi/2,a,b)`is simpler than `z["a'"],z["b'"] =  z.o:set_rotation (math.pi/2,z.a,z.b)`. For the moment I have not encountered any problem but ... However, the user is not obliged to do this and I do not use it in the main code!

Comment: I'd use keys `ap` and `bp` so you can use `.` in all cases  `z.ap`  and `z.bp`  using a key `a'` for a' and a key `bp` for b' is more confusing than you need, did you intend to treat these differently or is this just left from experiments for the last question?

Comment: It was an experiment. I have to use the form `z[ap]` and `z[bp]` if I want to get `a'` and `b'` in my TikZ code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really related to Lua, you need `\verb|c_a|` or similar for the underscore

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{document}
\parindent = 0pt
\begin{luacode}
tp=tex.print
z = {}

ap = "a'"
bp = "b'"  -- not used

z.a = {5,2}
z.b = {3,-2}
z.c_a = {3,2}
z[ap] = {99,0}
z.bp = {66,55}

tex.print("The stored coordinates are : "..'\\\\')
-- z.c_a = nil
for k,v in pairs(z) do
   tp("\\verb|" .. k .."|") tp(" represents :") tp("(" .. v[1]..","..v[2]..")")
   tex.print('\\\\')
end     
\end{luacode}
\end{document}
```